# Factory pattern in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, factory-pattern

Which is correct or suggested way to use factories in DDD?

Should factory method receive all necessary parameters from application service, or we are allowed to inject repositories and extract needed data inside factory?

Should it be (example 1):

```
public class UserTokenFactory : IUserTokenFactory
    {
        IUserTypeResourceRepository _userTypeResourceRepository;
        public UserTokenFactory(IUserTypeResourceRepository userTypeResourceRepository)
        {
            _userTypeResourceRepository = userTypeResourceRepository;
        }

        public async Task<UserToken> CreateWithAsync(User user)
        {
            var userTypeResources = await _userTypeResourceRepository.GetByUserTypeIdAsync(user.UserTypeId);

            //Some logic for creating user tokens
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

or as (Example 2)

```
public class UserTokenFactory : IUserTokenFactory
    {
        IUserTypeResourceRepository _userTypeResourceRepository;
        public UserTokenFactory(IUserTypeResourceRepository userTypeResourceRepository)
        {
            _userTypeResourceRepository = userTypeResourceRepository;
        }

        public UserToken CreateWith(User user, List<UserTypeResource> userTypeResources)
        {
            //Some logic for creating user tokens
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to inject services into factories. Your factory is basically a domain service which happens to create objects. However, I'd probably rely on the ISP here and define an interface like `IResolveUserType` rather than depending on the wider `IUserTypeResourceRepository` interface.

Comment: Interface segregation principal